# Solutions of linear systems

Tags: linear-algebra

I was reading *Linear Algebra* by Hoffman and Kunze and I encountered some concepts which were arguably not explained or expounded upon thoroughly. I will present my questions below, and I am looking for answers that do not invoke concepts like determinant, vector spaces etc. Note that this is an *introductory* chapter that assumes no knowledge of the above concepts.

Question 1: Consider a linear system A with *k* equations. If we form a new equation by taking a linear combination of these *k* equations, then any solution of A is also a solution of this new equation. Why is this so?

Question 2a: Consider two linear systems A and B. If each equation of A is a linear combination of the equations of B, then any solution of B is also a solution of A. Why is this so?

Question 2b: If each equation of A is a linear combination of the equations of B, then it is not necessary that any solution of A is also a solution of B. Why is this so?

Answer (score 1):

1) If $a = b$ and $c = d$, then $s a + t c = s b + t d$.

2a) Apply 1) to each equation of A.

2b) For example, $0 = 0$ is a linear combination of $a = b$ and $a = b$.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your answer to 1)? To me it seems that you are just taking a linear combination of the equations $a = b$ and $c = d$, but how does that answer the question?

Comment: A linear combination of more equations can be done two at a time.  Or you can say directly, if $a = b$ and $c = d$ and $e = f$ and ... then $sa + t c + ue + \ldots = sb + td + uf + \ldots$.

Comment: Yes, but why is it that taking a linear combination of a couple of equations *preserves* the solution set?

Comment: A solution is an assignment of values to variables that makes the equations true.  If equation 1 and equation 2 are true (after assigning the values), then so is any linear combination of them.